# C# How can I fill list Box with info from excel?

Tags: c#

so what I'm trying to do is fill a listBox with information from excel cells.
When I click button1 it brings up new form with listbox, now what i need is to add each cells that have info in them in Colon A in to listBox. Can anyone explain me how to do that ? any type of information would be help full. All so I'm not using OLEDB i have pre-defined file path to excel document. All so code sample would be grate. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its http://WhatHaveYouTried.com? In VIsual Studio, referenece the Microsoft.OFfice.Excel dll and then programatically open the XLS files and use the Excel Object Model to read the cells to populate your list box.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com) for reading Excel files